# boolean expression with min/max in nullif possible?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, boolean

is it possible to put a boolean expression with max or min into a nullif() statemtent?

for example

```
select 
    min(a) as b ---grabbing first value
    ,max(a) as  c --- grabbing last value but could be same as min value, this is the problem
    ,nullif(min(a), (min(a) = max(a))) ---my idea for a solution that didnt work
   from table
```

trying to weed out duplicate rows when a field has a value that only happens 1 time.  I am thinking there may be a way to do this with counting and then weeding out all values with a value over 1 but am not sure how to accomplish that. working on sql server 2005, need this in t-sql if possible, anything that will work on the server is ok though.

edit to provide more info: 
i am looking at a status history for orders in an order management system that tags each time a correction is requested with an id.  the id's are unique and numerical. in this format 1234  each orderid is unique and numerical as well in this format 1111111.2. a represents the unique correction id.  I want to look at the order, and if one correction id has already happened to grab the next one ideally, and the next after that and so on if possible. At very minimum i would want the MAX value and MIN value. i cannot just do two columns because that would count the min value twice (using my example) and will not give me accurate data

was trying to be simple with my example but its not providing enough info, here is more:

```
SELECT Cast(oi.orderid AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '.' 
                 + Cast(oi.orderitemid AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS OrderNumber,
       Min(oici.orderitemcorrectionid)                  AS a,
       Max(oici.orderitemcorrectionid)                  AS b
FROM   Orderitems oi
       LEFT JOIN orderitemcorrections oic
         ON oic.orderid = oi.orderid
            AND oic.orderitemid = oi.orderitemid
       LEFT JOIN orderitemcorrectionissues oici
         ON oici.orderitemcorrectionid = oic.orderitemcorrectionid
       LEFT JOIN correctiontypes ct
         ON ct.correctiontypeid = oici.correctiontypeid
GROUP  BY Cast(oi.orderid AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '.' 
                   + Cast(oi.orderitemid AS VARCHAR(MAX))
```

sample table data of above query:

```
OrderNumber a   b
1098048.1   1   2
1098210.1   160 160
1098222.1   78  78
1098300.1   31  31
1098408.1   4   4
1098462.1   224 224
1098468.1   602 602
1098492.2   1457 1457
```

above is data where a and b are the same
below is where they are different but i want to null any duplicates from a to b

```
1100268.1   181 191
1100256.1   306 379
```

more data, not grouped to show duplicates for rows. -- sample raw data

```
OrderNumber orderitemcorrectionid
1098048.1   1
1098048.1   2
1098210.1   160
1098210.1   160
```

Comment: You're better off explaining your root problem. If it is how to identify duplicates then please supply some example schema/data.

Comment: ok sorry about the lack of info, thought it was more of a syntax issue than that.  ill edit my post now

Comment: @MartinSmith just edited, let me know if i can do better to provide info

Comment: For me personally if you were to supply about 10 rows of dummy data and give the example results for that data it would likely make things much clearer.

Comment: @MartinSmith ok, editing again. just a few minutes

Comment: @MartinSmith added a table and a more detailed query to help

Comment: Yes I saw that, does your example data actually demonstrate the issue? Does it contain any duplicates? All the order numbers seem to have separate roots?

Comment: sorry my explanation was bad, the duplicates are in the columns a and b, for example for order # 1098210.1 the value is 160 in both columns, i want that to be null in column b, ive added another table to help show how it is without the grouping. showing that i do get more than 1 result for an ordernumber

Comment: So your final table (without grouping) is what the raw data looks like and you want a result that looks like the table you have titled "sample table data" except for if `a=b` then the value for b should be null?

Comment: exactly! sorry, ive always been bad at communicating my issues

Comment: To amend your original query you would just need `CASE WHEN Min(oici.orderitemcorrectionid) <> Max(oici.orderitemcorrectionid) THEN Max(oici.orderitemcorrectionid) END AS b` after all that but looks like you've got some other options to look at now.

Comment: @MartinSmith i think the case will do the job, trying it out now, will report back.  if that does it for me ill be a little embarrassed. should have thought of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the nullifying by using UNION, which removes duplicate rows.  I would do it like this

```
;with tmp AS (
    select
    CAST(oi.orderid as VARCHAR(MAX))+'.'+CAST(oi.orderitemid as VARCHAR(MAX)) as OrderNumber
    ,min(oici.orderitemcorrectionid) as a
    ,max(oici.orderitemcorrectionid) as b

    FROM
    Orderitems oi
    left join orderitemcorrections oic on oic.orderid = oi.orderid and oic.orderitemid = oi.orderitemid
    left join orderitemcorrectionissues oici on oici.orderitemcorrectionid = oic.orderitemcorrectionid
    left join correctiontypes ct on ct.correctiontypeid = oici.correctiontypeid
    GROUP BY 
    CAST(oi.orderid as VARCHAR(MAX))+'.'+CAST(oi.orderitemid as VARCHAR(MAX))
)
select OrderNumber, a
from tmp
union
select OrderNumber, b
from tmp
```

This puts the a's and b's into different rows, with Union taking care of removing duplicates.

Comment: this has helped me get closer to what i need, i have other problems with this query to get what i need but this got me past an obstacle, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

probably something like this:

```
SELECT Cast(oi.orderid AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '.' 
                 + Cast(oi.orderitemid AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS OrderNumber,
       COALESCE(Min(oici.orderitemcorrectionid),Max(oici.orderitemcorrectionid),0) AS a,
       COALESCE(Max(oici.orderitemcorrectionid),Min(oici.orderitemcorrectionid),0) AS b
FROM   Orderitems oi
       LEFT JOIN orderitemcorrections oic
         ON oic.orderid = oi.orderid
            AND oic.orderitemid = oi.orderitemid
       LEFT JOIN orderitemcorrectionissues oici
         ON oici.orderitemcorrectionid = oic.orderitemcorrectionid
       LEFT JOIN correctiontypes ct
         ON ct.correctiontypeid = oici.correctiontypeid
GROUP  BY Cast(oi.orderid AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '.' 
                   + Cast(oi.orderitemid AS VARCHAR(MAX))
```

However, I could be miss-understanding so be kind.